# Time series data - count occurrences of two sets

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization, data-structures

I have time series data. The data inside either has a value of 1 or 0 (could be true or false, or any other binary representation).

For example, I have two times series data variables:

```
byte[] a1 = new byte[]{1,0,0,1,0};
byte[] a2 = new byte[]{1,1,1,0,1};
```

I am now comparing the two arrays to count the number of times combinations happen:

```
Map<String,Integer> count = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

//all the time series arrays have the same length. In real life each would timeseries array would have a length of about 100
for(int i=0; i<ai.length(); i++){
    //a1[i] and a[2] occured. If this keys exists incremnt the count by one, otherwise insert the new key
    count.merge(a1[i]+":"+a2[i], 1, Integer::sum)
}
```

Essentially the output I am looking for is when `a1 = 1` how many times was `a2 = 1` and how many times was `a2 = 0`? As well, when `a1 = 0` how many times was `a2 = 1` and how many times was `a2 = 0`?

The problem I am facing is I am running billions of these comparisons in my program. The time to complete is much longer than I would want. I understand the nature of this will take quite long to complete, but was wondering if there is any other way to implement this to calculate it faster (I am already using multithreading, I am looking more into a change of possibly the algorithm, data structure change, open-source libraries, etc)?

Comment: How are you getting to billions of comparisons?  Do you have more than 2 time series at a time?  Are you solving this problem over and over again?  Are you asking lots and lots of questions about a given combination of time series?  The best suggestions are going to depend on a whole lot of things.

Comment: So I have about ~100,000 of these byte[] arrays. Every single array has the same data for the same period of time (array indexes will represent the same period in time for all the arrays). I am then doing this comparison to all of them with each other resulting in about 10,000,000,000 (100,000 x 100,000) of these comparisons.

Comment: What is comparison result? 4 numbers: count of 0-0, 0-1,1-0 and 1-1 pairs?

Comment: What then happens with these 10,000,000,000 results? Are they used for further calculations (if yes, then what it is and how it is calculated) ? Are they simply stored to the database ? Or maybe they are printed on paper and somebody is reviewing them (just kidding - no human being is able to read 10,000,000,000 lines of text )

Comment: All the records get stored into a database. From here I filter out some of the results when needed, but I am more concerned with the resultset before it gets put into the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the large number of results that you are trying to produce, I would suggest that you look for ways to micro-optimize and divide up work.  There isn't a fancy way to make it fewer operations, just make them efficient ones.

I would therefore recommend that you turn your byte arrays into `BitSet`s.  Your 4 counts should be done by doing a `cardinality()` on `a.and(b)` (1,1), `a.andNot(b)` (1,0), `a.or(b).flip()` (0,0) and `a.flip().and(b)` (0,1).  In terms of synchronizing work, you should hand out work as all pairwise combinations of blocks of (experiment with this figure) say 20 arrays with 20 arrays.  A large enough block of work to be real work.  A small enough one to describe source and result in reasonably small messages.  Each piece of work should be processed single threaded by a single worker.  Think carefully about how to store the final data - a lot of your work will be building that data structure.  The thing to avoid at all costs is a hash-based data structure that causes you to be seeking all over random places in memory.  Much better to sort data in place.

If you can, focus on cache coherency.

Comment: Thanks so much! I have run a few benchmarks now using bitset and it is definitely MUCH quicker. Sorry, could you please explain how the flip functions? The flip function requires an index, but I see in your example there is no index.

Comment: Is the or.flip() = XOR?

Comment: @user2924127 By my reading, flip just reverses 0 and 1.  So I intended `a.or(b).flip()` to be `not (A or B)`, meaning both bits are 0.  But I didn't test.  If it doesn't work that way, you can instead count the 1s and subtract that from the length.